# VMware Converter for creating virtual machine for Vmplayer

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-player, vmware-converter

VMware Converter is free and converts a running machine to a VMware virtual machine. The machine can be your local machine or a remote machine on the network . however, The VMware Converter only allows creation of vmware infrastructure virtual machine(Creates a virtual machine that a VMware Infrastructure product manages).  I'm using  vmplayer 3.0.0 build-197124 on Vista Home Premium .

Supported VMware Infrastructure products:

- ESX Server 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0
- ESXi 3.5 and 4.0 Embedded
- VMware vCenter Server 2.0, 2.5 and 4.0

How can i create a virtual machine from a live partition and run it on vmplayer 3.0.0 build-197124. I'm also willing to buy Vmware Workstation if there is support for such a feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless that have reduced the functionality recently, you can use the converter to create a VM on a VMWare Server instance (no Infrastructure/ESX/ESXi/...) as I have done this previously (creating a VM on one of our test/dev VM host machines from an old laptop that was about to be rebuilt).

Once you have a VMWare Server compatible VM you should just be able to use that in VMWare Player.

This still means having another VMWare installation going, on the machine to be imaged or another server, but VMWare Server is free to use.

Comment: I'm using VMware vCenter Converter Standalone version=4.0.1, build=build-161434