# Mount Image tool for Acronis True Image 2010 home

Tags: acronis-trueimage

Is there a Mount Image tool for Acronis True Image 2010 home edition? I do not want to install the software, just view contents of a .tib file created with Acronis True Image 2010 home?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only Acronis can understand .tib files.

If you don't want to install it, the only other option is to use the Acronis LiveCD, which is a boot CD that doesn't require installation.

There are products that take backups in universal formats, such as zip or iso.

Zip products do not normally take backups of the running system, but rather of selected directories.

Some free backup tools that can create an iso out of the running system are:

[Disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx)
[VMware vCenter Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/)

You can also use a disk-imaging product that will image the whole disk to another.
However, such products do not compress the hard disk.
Disk compression normally requires a proprietary backup format.

Comment: Thanks..that means a Vendor lock-in here!! Can you suggest any similar software which can provide the functionality i want?

Comment: @iceman: I have added some more info.

Comment: @iceman: I must comment that I don't see anything wrong with vendor lock-in for a good product. I use Acronis myself, and am very satisfied.

Comment: thanks, let me try these tools and come back with comments and questions if any

Comment: I'm not very keen on using Vmware : http://superuser.com/questions/79788/vmware-converter-for-creating-virtual-machine-for-vmplayer and any time I tried using it one a live machine, it errors out : http://superuser.com/questions/82374/error-while-vmware-converter-for-creating-virtual-machine-for-vmplayer . I'll try the MS tool and report. The problem with Acronis is even if its  a very good tool,the .tib created by one version of it is not readable by another version.

Comment: @iceman: Acronis only backups used sectors, rather than producing an image, and one can also specify directories to ignore. In my experience it compresses disk data by a factor of about 2. Each version comes with a live CD that you can conserve to deal with old versions. All in all, comparing with the benefits, I don't see this as much of an inconvenience.

Comment: It's not clear to me, why Acronis has implemented conversion from TIB to VHD, but not to ISO or NRG. Any hints how to convert to any of those? Or somehow extract specific files?

Comment: @dma_k: See [this thread](http://forum.acronis.com/forum/9995), but otherwise please start a new post for the question.